# passing a URL to test against with nose testconfig

Tags: python, selenium, nose

is there a way to configure test-config so that i can pass a URL in command line i.e. 'nosetests --tc=systest_url test_suit.py'

I need to  run my selenium tests against dev and systest environments when performing builds on teamcity. Our team decided to use python for UI tests and Im more a Java guy and I'm tring to figure out how the plugin works it looks like i can store the url in yaml and pass the file to the --tc command but doesn't seem to work

the code i inherited looks like this :

```
URL = config['test' : 'https://www.google.com', ]


class BaseTestCase(unittest.TestCase, Navigation):
    @classmethod
    def setUpClass(cls):
        cls.driver = webdriver.Firefox()
        cls.driver.implicitly_wait(5)
        cls.driver.maximize_window()

        cls.driver.get(URL)
```

which obviously is not working

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using the [nose-testconfig --tc](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/nose-testconfig#command-line-options) option you can override a configuration value. Separate the key from the value using a colon. For example,

```
nosetests test.py --tc=url:dev.example.com
```

will make the value available in `config['url']`.

```
from testconfig import config

def test_url_is_dev():
    assert 'dev' in config['url']
```

Comment: thanks, worked. Do i always need to pass the complete url. Is there a way to define url value in config? I suppose that gets the config parameters from the config file, ini/yaml/json etc?

Comment: You could pass any value and parse it to your liking in the setup method. Testconfig, indeed, also supports config files. Take a look at Mauro Baraldi's [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/37390385/2027280).

Answer (score 2):

There is a plugin for nose, the [nosetest-config](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/nose-testconfig). You can specify some config file and pass filename to `--tc-file` arg from nose.

**config.ini**

```
[myapp_servers]
main_server = 10.1.1.1
secondary_server = 10.1.1.2
```

In your test file you can load the config.

**test_app.py**

```
from testconfig import config

def test_foo():
     main_server = config['myapp_servers']['main_server']
```

Than, call nose with args

```
nosetests -s --tc-file example_cfg.ini
```

As described in docs, you can use other config files type like YAML, JSON or even Python modules.